# How can I read tron smartcontract storage?

Tags: ethereum, tron, tronweb

I want to read the TRON smart contract storage.
I know, that at ethereum we can use web3.eth.getStorageAt().
I can't find any similar or equivalent implementation for TronWeb API.

Answer (score 0):

Tron does not provide this API.

The only way to read contract storage is by using a public variable.